# How to get bibtex to work after El Capitan update

Tags: bibtex, compiling

After the El Capitan update I had to go through my preferences and change the path files for LaTeX to compile but my references are still not working. Trying to compile gives the following warning:

```
Process started

This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015) The top-level auxiliary file: Plan.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file Plan.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file Plan.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file Plan.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)
```

Does anyone have any advice for how to deal with this? I am using TexMaker with MacTex. Everything worked perfectly before the upgrade and nothing has changed in the file since the upgrade.

A MWE of a file that does not compile is:

```
%_________________Preamble Start___________________________________________
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twopage]{scrreprt}
%_________________Encoding_________________________________________________
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%_________________Referencing__________________________________________
 \usepackage[style=authoryear-comp,natbib]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{References.bib} 
%this means you dont have to stipulate if you are referencing a figure etc
\usepackage{cleveref}
%_________________graphics_____________________________________________
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\citep{fulton2014integrated}

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

And the bib file is References.bib with one reference:

```
@article{fulton2014integrated,
  title={An integrated approach is needed for Ecosystem Based Fisheries Management: insights from ecosystem-level management strategy evaluation},
  author={Fulton, Elizabeth A and Smith, Anthony DM and Smith, David C and Johnson, Penelope},
  journal={PloS one},
  volume={9},
  number={1},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Public Library of Science}
}
```

And Here are my preferences:

[image: Preferences for TexMaker]

Just to summarise my discussion with moewe I needed to change the Bib(la)tex field to "/Library/TeX/texbin/biber" % (i.e. remove the aux and change to biber rather than bibtex).

Comment: This does seem more like a problem with an `.aux` file that wasn't made to be processed by BibTeX. Can you show us the document you produced this with? If you use `biblatex` as the tag suggests, your document probably expects to be compiled with Biber and not with BibTeX.

Comment: I have had a lot of problem after the update to El Capitan. I suggest you to control the following: 1) be sure the changes in the path are permanent and 2) if the problem is still present try to reinstall the entire tex packet (last release should be 2015) and then reinstall also the TeXMaker application.

Comment: Unfortunately Im with 2015 already, should I still download it? @moewe which parts of the document are necessary to see in the MWE?

Comment: Maybe it helps to re-install TeX Live 2015. But it looks like your TeX installation works and something else is fishy. We would need to see your bibliography/citation commands. Please make sure that the MWE also exhibits the exact same problem.

Comment: Thanks @moewe I have added a MWE that comes up with exactly the same issue, if you have any insights it would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: the references are missing for testing.

Comment: @Johannes_B apologies, I have added them now

Comment: You are running `bibtex`, but you need to run `biber` [Biblatex with Biber: Configuring my editor to avoid undefined citations](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/154767)

Comment: I didn't have this problem before I upgraded, why would it change after my upgrade? As far as Im aware I have always run bibtex. Thanks for your help, I appreciate it.

Comment: Johannes_B's analysis seems bang on. Maybe you had a really old installation with an old version of `biblatex`. In the old days, the default (if no `backend` option was passed to `biblatex`) backend was BibTeX, but this has changed to Biber.

Comment: I get this error when I make that change `Process started

INFO - This is Biber 2.1 INFO - Logfile is 'Plan.aux.blg' ERROR - Cannot find control file 'Plan.aux.bcf'! - did you pass the "backend=biber" option to BibLaTeX? INFO - ERRORS: 1

Process exited with error(s)`

Comment: and if I use biber.exe I get `Error : could not start the command : "/Library/TeX/texbin/biber.exe" "Plan".aux`

Comment: The first message shows that you have mis-configured your editor. You need to follow the instructions in Johannes_B's link, you will have an `aux` too much in your settings. The second error just confuses me, you are on OS X aren't you? In that case you will not call `biber.exe` (`.exe` is for Windows executables).

Comment: Ok, I will double check - I thought I had copied it exactly but I have obviously missed something. Yep Im OS X so I will leave that out.

Comment: As far as I can tell my preferences are the same bar mines for MacTeX, can you see anything wrong? I have edited my question to show the preferences.

Comment: Yes, you have a superfluous `aux` in the line for "Bib(la)tex", it should read `"/path/to/biber" %` *without* the `.aux`.

Comment: Thank you, I thought that was just hidden after the %. It now works but throws up: `Unicode char \u8:́ not set up for use with LaTeX` as an error. Sorry for the protracted problems, and thank you massively for your help.

Comment: In my actual document that is, not my MWE. Is this error unrelated to the referencing? It locates it in the bibliography section

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31006/discussion-between-moewe-and-paulbarr).